# Is it OK to ask an old question again?

Tags: discussion

I need to ask something that has been asked before (not by me), but the answer was negative or there was no answer. The last question was 3 years ago, and it doesn't have an accepted answer.

After 3 years it is possible that a negative answer could become positive. But unless someone is actively looking for old no longer correct-answers those will remain outdated.

Would it be OK if I ask my question today although, technically speaking, there are existing duplicate questions already?

If not, is there a way to boost the attention on those old questions to see If I can get a new answer?

Comment: @Servy - Although that question is similar yes, it talks about of my own questions, do we apply the same rules for questions someone else posted?

Comment: It discusses both situation.

Comment: @Servy - I disagree he is only talking about his own question, and the answer is to edit it or put a bounty. Most people don't like others editing their questions, so the only possible way to go is put a bounty?

Comment: Whether someone likes their question being edited is irrelevant. If you have a quality, appropriate, useful edit to make that makes the question objectively better, make it.  If you don't, then don't.  You can of course add a bounty to another's question.

Comment: @Servy - Ok, so basically, either I put a bounty or I can do nothing, since I don't know of the subject matter and I can not add valuable information, that is why I want to create a question in the first place. It seems a limitation to me.

Comment: Look at the second page of the bounty where it lists the reasons. What you are describing is *exactly* covered in those reasons. The bounty is the appropriate tool rather than asking a question that will get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelT - Thanks for pointing that out, although I read the whole Set bounties page and couldn't find it. In any case I think it is a limitation that you need to set a bounty to be able to get an answer to an old question, what happens if you don't happen enough reputation, for example? In any case I found questions on Meta talking about the topic already so I did my voting on them.

Comment: @Dzyann if you don't have sufficient reputation to start a bounty, you should invest more in the site and community to make sure that you have a reasonable understanding of the site, community and their expectations for how things work. People creating bounties on poor questions is one of the fairly persistent mod flags that show up on some sites (it prevents closing the question) - one *shouldn't* be drawing attention to poor questions.

Comment: @MichaelT - If a user has low reputation doesn't mean he doesn't understand the site, or that doesn't know what he is doing. These are Q&A site, normally people post question they need answers soon, and if a question has been asked with no good answer and is ancient, we are hindering people by not having a good mechanics to re-bump it, that doesn't depend on the user expertise (as normal questions are). In any case, that is my opinion, I won't award a bounty, because I do not think I will get the answer I need. And I do appreciate the time you took for reading and answering my comments.

Comment: @Dzyann They may have an understanding... but the low reputation *does* mean that they don't have much invested in the site (that is what the reputation best reflects, in my opinion). Do consider that if you don't think you'd get the answer you need after putting a bounty on the older question (which promises more reputation than that from a new question and accept), you likely wouldn't get the answer you need from the question you would ask either.

Comment: @MichaelT - Well, I really brought this up for the purpose of understanding the position of the community on the matter. I still think the current situation is limited and unwelcoming. You can be using the site for years without earning reputation because your issues are already solved by existing content, etc. And that one day you need an answer and the question already exists but it is ancient. I do agree that trying to address such situation might be like looking for aliens, not very likely to happen. On my question I will address Microsoft.